# How can I make the text entered into the username field copy to the password field so they are the same?

Tags: javascript

I know this is easy but I want to make the password automatically be entered as the same thing as the username but I cant get it to copy right in real time.

```
<%=I18n._("Username")%>:</td>
    <td><%data.printTextField(out,UserPerson.FIELD_NAME,null,"text",100,0);%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="<%=data.isFacebook ? "display: none" : "" %>">
    <td class="nowrap fieldheader"><span class="note-fieldrequired">*</span> <%=I18n._("Password")%>:</td>
    <td><%data.printPasswordField(out,UserPerson.FIELD_PASSWORD,null,"password",100,0);%></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a username field and a password field like these:

```
<input type="text" id="input-username">
<input type="password" id="input-password">
```

You have to attach an event listener to the username field (using [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript)), e.g. like this:

```
const inputUsername = document.getElementById('input-username');
const inputPassword = document.getElementById('input-password');
inputUsername.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  inputPassword.value = inputUsername.value
})
```

However, ask yourself: do you really need to do this?